# add_rewrite_rule only works when flush first

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have the following code in my functions.php file. I have a page **projects**. I have two custom post types: **project** and **projecttype**. An individual project post has it's own permalink */projects/project-name*. Projecttypes do need to show the 'projects' page.

My code checks if the url is a subpage of */projects/*. If the subpage is a projecttype, it loads the template for the projects page (id 8).

```php
if(substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 11 ) === '/projects/'){
  $request_subpage = str_replace('/', '', str_replace('/projects/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
  if($request_subpage !== '') {
    $valid_subpage_url = false;
    $project_types = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'projecttype', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    foreach( $project_types as $project_type ) :
      if( $project_type->post_name === $request_subpage ) :
        $valid_subpage_url = true;
        break;
      endif;
    endforeach;
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
    if($valid_subpage_url) add_rewrite_rule( "^projects\/$request_subpage$", "index.php?page_id=8", 'top');

  }
}
```

When I uncomment `flush_rewrite_rules();` my code works. When I don't flush the rewrite rules, it does not work (all projecttype subpages return a 404). Since flush is an expensive operation, I probably shouldn't use it.

What's going on here?

Comment: Sounds like projecttype could just be a taxonomy for projects?

Comment: @JKL For what purpose do you create `projecttype` posts that load the same page? As noted, the *name suggests* that `projecttype` could be taxonomy. What does `projects` page do? Depending on the `projecttype` displays different content?

Comment: @nmr the projects page shows content and displays projects (custom post type). When going to _/projects/[projecttype]/_ it displays the post content and title from the projecttype, and displays only the projects that have this projecttype (in an advanced custom field)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with rules occurs, because rule for a given `projecttype` is added when you visit relevant URL.

Every time you visit one of `projects/{projectstype}/` addresses and flush rewrite rules, 
**they are deleted and only one rule** (only for current project type) is saved/created.

You can add your code to [`request`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request) filter hook, then there is no need to add rewrite rules. 
All query vars, that are set by rules (you set only `page_id`), you can set manually.

```
add_filter( 'request' , 'se336968_request' );
function se336968_request( $query_vars )
{
    if(substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 11 ) === '/projects/'){
        $request_subpage = str_replace('/', '', str_replace('/projects/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        if($request_subpage !== '') {
            $project_types = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'projecttype', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
            foreach( $project_types as $project_type ) {
                if( $project_type->post_name === $request_subpage ) {

                          // your current rewrite 
                    $query_vars['page_id'] = 8;
                    $query_vars['post_type'] = 'page';

                    //  --- to open "projecttype" type post from URL ---
                    // $query_vars['post_type'] = 'projecttype';
                    // $query_vars['projecttype'] = $request_subpage;
                    // unset( $query_vars['page_id'], $query_vars['p'], $query_vars['pagename'], $query_vars['name'] );

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $query_vars;
}
```